# Filter nested table in view sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a view based on this query

```
with fields as (
    select id, data_id, value
    from test
    where data_id in (123, 345)
),
counted as (
    SELECT id, data_id, sum(meta.count) as count
    FROM fields
    LEFT JOIN meta ON meta.field_id = fields.id 
    group by data_id, meta.field_id, value
)

SELECT id, data_id, count
FROM (
    SELECT id, data_id, count,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY data_id ORDER BY count DESC) dest_rank
    FROM counted
) t
WHERE dest_rank = 1
```

However `where data_id in (123, 345)` needs to be custom so I can write `SELECT * from my_view where data_id in (123, 345)` or with a JOIN such as

```
SELECT * FROM another_table LEFT JOIN my_view ON my_view.data_id = another_table.data_id
```

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: What you want is a function that returns a table.  A good place to start is the documentation:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a function with your custom values as parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function (a int, b int)
RETURNS TABLE(id int, data_id int, count int) AS $$
    with fields as (
        select id, data_id, value
        from test
        where data_id in ($1, $2)
    ),
    ... 
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And then you could do this query:

```
SELECT my_function(123, 456);
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the same result using a JOIN ? For instance `SELECT * from another_table where LEFT JOIN my_view  ON my_view.data_id =  another_table.data_view`

Comment: I am not sure if I giot the intention of the question: Do you want to remove the WHERE clause in your view and then JOINING a table maybe with the data 123 and 456? Yes this is possible of course.